# I want to create response and request functions.R esponse receives a string as input and sends it to the user.Request returns the user's last message

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Library:
https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.15/
I tried for a long time, but I can’t pass any value to the bot function

this code is one of the options but it does not work

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext


class ConsoleView:
    def __init__(self,token):
        self.updater = Updater(token=token)
        self.dispatcher = self.updater.dispatcher
        
        self.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", self.start))
        
        self.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(self.button_pressed))
        
    def response(self, update, context):
        update.message.reply_text('здесь чтото будет')
        
    def request(self, update, context):
        keyboard = []
        for i in range(1,self.y+1):
            keyboard.append([InlineKeyboardButton(f"Option {i}", callback_data=f"{i}")])
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        update.message.reply_text('Выберите кнопочку:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
        
    def button_pressed(self, update, context)
        query = update.callback_query
        query.answer()
        query.edit_message_text(text=f'Нажата кнопка: {query.data}, вы выбрали тототото')
        
    def start(self, update, context):
        update.message.reply_text('проверка звука')
        
    def run(self):
        self.updater.start_polling()
        self.updater.idle()
        



console_view = ConsoleView("6357433531:AAHzxBRRtQpni7aFLcjRcbh2FFRxyFSIr0o")

console_view.run()
```

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.